# Parsing POJO to JSON Object

Tags: java, pojo, json, org.json

I have to convert a POJO to JSON object but i am encountering a problem.
My POJO has four variables and their getters and setters.

`private String RouteCoord;
 private String RouteName;
 private String freqArray;
 private Double AvgTime;`

I have declared a list of objects

```
List<KPIsStructure> listOfKPIsObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

I run a for loop in which i create instances of my POJO class and add them to the already declared list (listOfKPIsObjects)

```
for (int i=0;i<routes.length;i++){

    KPIsStructure innerObject = new KPIsStructure();
    innerObject.setRouteCoord(routes[i][1]);
    innerObject.setRouteName(routes[i][0]);
    innerObject.setAvgTime(AvgTime[i]);
    innerObject.setfreqArray(freqArray[i]);
    listOfKPIsObjects.add(innerObject);
}
```

Then there is this another for loop to make a nested JSON Object

```
for (int i=0;i<listOfKPIsObjects.size();i++){
    JSONObject temp = new JSONObject(listOfKPIsObjects.get(i));
    processedJson.put("journey_"+(i+1), temp);
}
```

I return processedJson. The problem is the result is missing one of the variables (String freqArray) of the POJO class.

> {"journey_1":{"avgTime":12.283334,"routeCoord":"435,345-789,1011","routeName":"tty-keskustori"},"journey_2":{"avgTime":12.283334,"routeCoord":"123,456-789,1011","routeName":"hervanta-tty"},"journey_3":{"avgTime":12.283334,"routeCoord":"123,456-789,1011","routeName":"kaleva-keskustori"}}

I have tried passing the variables of the class as string and it works and it also shows that the string ***freqArray*** is not empty.

```
String toJson = "{\"RouteName:"+listOfKPIsObjects.get(i).getRouteName()+",RouteCoordinates:"+listOfKPIsObjects.get(i).getRouteCoord()+",AvgTime:"+listOfKPIsObjects.get(i).getAvgTime()+",VisitFrequency:"+listOfKPIsObjects.get(i).getfreqArray()+"}";
```

Doing it this way takes away the idea of mapping from POJO to JSON object and vice versa and makes it inconvenient.

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong here. I am using org.json.

Comment: Have you tried Gson?

Comment: I used it but i don't want to go back to Gson. I had too many problems with nested JSON objects.

Comment: have you tried with primitive double?